# Java vs Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I want to know how similar Java is to the Android SDK. I am aware that the Android SDK uses Java, but I'm also aware there are many different things like manifest files and XML files and whatnot. I want to know if the SDK is similar enough that if I were to make a simple `Swing` based GUI program, would I be able to port it within a day? Is this realistic?

Comment: That depends entirely on the GUI, your skill level, and the size of the application. There is no real answer to this question.

Comment: Well are there much more complex techniques that I have to learn in android? because in Java I can make a GUI with buttons and textfields with actionlisteners and all within 4-5 hours.

Comment: There aren't complicated *techniques*, really. The UI elements and listeners are similar in their implementations. But, as Ted mentioned, it is unrealistic to assume you'll be able to do quick ports between mediums like this.

Comment: Porting and building from scratch are different things. As with Swing, you can with Android build a GUI with buttons and text fields with action listeners in a few hours. However, an Android UI would usually be designed quite differently from a Swing desktop UI. So porting means redesign as well as implementation.

Comment: Then if you had the same level of familiarity with Android, you could probably build an Android app in the same amount of time, I'd say. As with everything else, budget time to actually *learn* the platform first.

Comment: Ahh. that's what I wanted to know. I thought porting to android would be just implementing a class or two and compiling it into an apk but I guess its a lot more work than that.

Answer (score 2):

The conceptual UI models of Swing and Android are considerably different. Other than the most trivial UI, it would be unrealistic to expect to port anything in a day. (I say this based on the experience of doing ports just like that.)